# These Mammals Had a Good Run, So What Happened?

Tags: evolution, mammals, extinction

One of the great mysteries of the mammals is that some of the longest-lasting just aren't with us today.  The list of these puzzling unfortunates is as follows:

### Paleomerycidae

[image]

DURATION:
55.8 to 4.9 million years ago

### Hyaenodonta

[image]

DURATION:
63.3 to 11.1 million years ago

### Merycoidodontoidea

[image]

DURATION:  35 to 5 million years ago

### Hyracodontidae

[image]

DURATION:  55.8 to 20 million years ago

### Leptictidia

[image]

DURATION:  70 to 33 million years ago

### Entelodontidae

[image]

DURATION:
37.2 to 16.3 million years ago

### Amphiocyonidae

[image]

DURATION:
46.2 to 1.8 million years ago

### Protoceratidae

[image]

DURATION:
46.2 to 4.9 million years ago

If all these numbers mean anything, it's that these groups had withstood millions of years of countless, various changes in their environments.  They had lived so long, yet despite their apparent flexibility, they tripped at the finish line.

The simple question is:  ***Why?***

Comment: @JohnWDailey The questions is locked now, new comments are not possible any more. Please discuss this issue in the chat, the comments are not for extended discussion, so please stick to the rules.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45872/discussion-on-question-by-johnwdailey-these-mammals-had-a-good-run-so-what-happ).